# Java error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I run this code:

```
package jmv;

public class euler3 {
    int x=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x=0 ; x < 6008 ; x++){
            if(6008 % x == 0){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at euler2.euler2.main(euler2.java:7)
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: for (int x=1 ; x < 6008 ; x++){

Comment: start your loop with x=1. Java doesn't allow you to divide by 0 zero because is undefined

Comment: you get that error because you are dividing a number by Zero which result to undefined. Try to start your loop to int x = 1

Comment: To those of us who've been working in Java and related languages for a while that error message is completely obvious. I had not even noticed on a first reading that it used the symbol / rather than the word divide. To those down-voting, try to think back to when all this was new to you.

Answer (score 3):

The error is exactly what it states - you can't divide by zero. In your case, when you do `if(6008 % x == 0)` you are taking the modulus of 6008 and 0 - that's undefined. Try `x=1` instead of `x=0`

Answer (score 2):

You set

```
int x=0
```

and then compute the modulus, that is the remainder when dividing by x

```
6008 % x
```

So effectively you are dividing by zero, which is impossible. Try starting with x = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Your code started `x` at 0. That means, your code will try to run `6008 % 0`, which causes the division by zero error.

Change `int x = 0` to `int x = 1` to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to division by zero as the modulo operator (%) is essentially a divide.

Start from `x=1` instead.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x=1 ; x < 6008 ; x++){
            if(6008 % x == 0){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

start x from 1 so that `6008 % 0`  The first iteration of loop which is causing error can be avoided..

Note: If zero is must add/print it manually before loop starts.

```
public class euler3 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x=1 ; x < 6008 ; x++){
            if(6008 % x == 0){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: A tiny bit of text explaining that changing the loop so that it starts at 1 avoids division by zero would make this a better answer.